# SWT - Advice needed about Text Boxes / Tables / Adding and Removing values

Tags: java, layout, dialog, swt

I would really like some advice on how to proceed with the following requirement.

I am going to create a new dialog. In the dialog I want 2 boxes.  1 box with populated values and the other empty.  I will also need a add and remove button.  They will move selected values from one box to the other.

Here is a example of that I am needing to code.

[image]

1. Would I use text boxes or tables?
2. Would the boxes and boxes be in the same component?
3. Is it possible to have the add button over the remove button?

I am really looking for advice on what to use boxes or tables and how to layout the components to achieve something like the image above.

Comment: Which of my suggestions did you use in the end?

Comment: I actually used the two table suggestion.  It worked out very well.

Comment: You always help!  You have been a great help for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [`DualList`](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/opal/wiki/DualList) from the opal project. This should be exactly what you want.

[image]

If you want to do it yourself, use either two `Table`s with just one column each, or two `List`s.

The layout would be:

```
Composite(GridLayout, 3 columns)
|
|- First List/Table
|
|- Composite(GridLayout, 1 column)
|  |- Button add
|  |- Button delete
|
|- Second List/Table
```

**Edit**:

As a matter of fact, is designed something very similar as an answer to a different question. Have a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12743043/1449199).