# Eclipse SWT : Multi Select Widget from left column to right column

Tags: user-interface, swt

[image]

I am developing a plugin that uses SWT.
In one of the windows of the plugin I need to add widgets that look like the one above.I could not find an appropriate name, so, the image.

What it does is, selects the items from left column to the right column and vice versa using the buttons in the middle. Once the items are moved, they are removed from the left column and added to the right column and vice versa.

**Question 1:** What is the exact name for this setup?
**Question 2:** Is there any existing swt class that implements this setup I can reuse?

Comment: Also see [What's this UI pattern called?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2852995/1281433), which provides an answer to **Question 1**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [`DualList`](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/opal/wiki/DualList) from the opal project. This should be exactly what you want.

[image]

If you want to do it yourself, use either two `Table`s with just one column each, or two `List`s.

The layout would be:

```
Composite(GridLayout, 3 columns)
|
|- First List/Table
|
|- Composite(GridLayout, 1 column)
|  |- Button add
|  |- Button addAll
|  |- Button delete
|  |- Button deleteAll
|
|- Second List/Table
```

**Edit**:

As a matter of fact, is designed something very similar as an answer to a different question. Have a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12743043/1449199).