# swt widget (pallet widget) for group selection

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I am looking to have a widget like below screen in my rcp application. I tried to find an existing one however I could not find one. Anyone can please help. Do you think I will have to create my own (by having two list and arrows and then writing arrow event code).

[image: pallet widget for multi selection]

Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SWT - Advice needed about Text Boxes / Tables / Adding and Removing values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715596/swt-advice-needed-about-text-boxes-tables-adding-and-removing-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at [Opal](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/opal/)

The have a widget called `DualList`, see Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Hi Tom, I am already going through this opal however I was having some issue with this. I modified the code according to my requirement (as in above it uses countries list). I am trying to show a list of string of person (hardcoded a list of String). however it does not show any entry in the left list. I am not if this is because I am not using DLItem and using String list or something else.

Comment: The API does not support Strings. You can add only items from type DLItem (you just have to wrap your String within such an object).

Comment: I used list instead of table and tableItem. Thanks Tom.